# Mapa para Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na Unity3D que se assemelha ao aplicativo Waze, porém para isso não poderei utilizar uma API do Google Maps, por exemplo, o Static Maps, pois precisarei de algo que seja offline e me possibilite a implementação de modelos 3D em determinada latitude/longitude.

Não precisarei de um mapa tão detalhado, para este projeto são necessárias somente os map tiles com ruas e quarteirões, sem a necessidade de demais informações como nome de ruas, nome de avenidas, de estabelecimentos, residências, etc.

Existe algo deste tipo que eu possa implementar em C#?

Comment: Caro colega, na minha opinião esta sua pergunta está bastante ampla para este site. Como vc já pode perceber, a resposta que recebeu só tem links para sugestões de ferramentas, e como este site não é um fórum (leia [ask] e faça o [tour], se não fez ainda), o tipo de resposta que a sua pergunta fomenta não é conteúdo ideal. Sugiro tentar alguma coisa (talvez com alguma das ferramentas que já lhe foram sugeridas) e editar a questão para tornar a dúvida mais objetiva.

Comment: sua pergunta ta mais pro site do Game development

Comment: @Leandro até concordo, mas como não temos ele em português, cabe aqui mesmo sem problemas. O problema da pergunta ainda é o que o Luiz Vieira comentou. Fechei ela, mas se for editada e tiver mais detalhes que ajudem responder, a gente reabre sem problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que há umas quantas disponíveis:

- [SimpleMap](https://github.com/agafonoff2000/SimpleMap)
- [Great Maps](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps)
- [Sharp Map](https://github.com/SharpMap)
- [Arcgis](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/take-maps-offline.htm)

Aqui fica um exemplo de como usar o Great Maps, optei por esse por ter um numero maior de downloads o que não é indicativo de coisa alguma.

```
map.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.CacheOnly;
map.SetPositionByKeywords("Coldrerio, Switzerland");

var markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
var marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
map.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
```

Dependendo do Provider escolhido a informação do mapa é diferente. Por exemplo O BingProvider que eu usei só tem informação das Cidades e estradas, enquanto os de Satelite so permitem ver as casas. Se usar um provider Hybrid poderá ver os dois ao mesmo tempo.

É também de notar que terá que utilizar o modo `Server` pelo menos uma vez para ter informação do mapa disponível.

Comment: Foi legal você ter adicionado um exemplo. Mas, qualquer usuário futuro interessado ainda vai ter sérias dificuldades. Como esse mapa pode ser utilizado para posicionar algo em 3D? Ou, como o retorno dessas chamadas é utilizado dentro da Unity? (Note que essas dúvidas estão na pergunta do AP. Eu [já disse](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145402/mapa-para-unity3d#comment300033_145402) que acho a pergunta ampla, mas ainda assim uma resposta precisaria tentar responder ao menos tangencialmente a elas).

Comment: @LuizVieira É uma questão de escolher o provider adequado. Por exemplo os Hybrid providers dão informação das casas, enquanto os normais não dão.

Comment: Bom, eu ainda acho que isso não responde às perguntas. Mas, como eu disse, a culpa não é necessariamente sua.